# TypeError: predict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'callbacks'

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, time-series

I am using Keras 2.2.4 version with tensorboard 1.10.0 and tensorflow                1.10.0 in Python 3,6 version. But I can't use callbacks on predict method.

I have one saved model, so first I loaded the model and then trying to predict the test data and display it in tensor board. It's throwing an error, but as per keras documents predict function looks like:

predict(x, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None, callbacks=None)

```py
import keras.callbacks
from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model(strPath_model)
tb_test = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=strPath_model_test_logs,histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=True)

y_test = model.predict(test_val_X, verbose=1, callbacks=[tb_test])
```

TypeError: predict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'callbacks'

Comment: Looking at the source code of the keras 2.2.4 release, the `predict` function is defined as: `def predict(self, x,batch_size=None, verbose=0,steps=None): .... `
Apparently, the callbacks options got removed and that's why you get the described error. However, it seems like also previous releases do not have an callbacks argument for the predict function. Maybe this is just an documentation issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keras documentation is built from git master, so it usually contains features that are not part of any current Keras release. This is the case of callbacks for `model.predict`, and to use them you would have to install Keras from git master as:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/keras-team/keras.git
```

You should remove other Keras' versions before installing master.

Comment: @SamudranilRoy You need to be more specific, we cannot guess problems.

Comment: First I installed git in myenv by using conda install git and then ran the above mentioned command. Then in my code I used model.predict(test_X, callbacks = [tensor_board]). It shows TypeError: predict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'callbacks'

Comment: Did you remove any previous keras versions before installing master?

Comment: Also note that anaconda might be interfering, I tried using pip in plain python on Linux and this works fine.

Comment: Anaconda can be a problem although I removed previously presented Keras